# Scanning a csv file for a string in R

Tags: r, function, csv

I would like to be able to scan a csv file row by row in R and exclude the rows that contain the word "target".

The problem is that the data comes from different places and the word "target" can come up in a number of different columns in the data frame.

So I need a line in a function that will look for this string, and if it is not present, then append that row to a new data frame (that I will then write out as a new csv).

Any and all help gratefully recieved.

Comment: Do it the other way round: 1) Read the entire file into a data frame. 2) Scan each column using `grep` and `lapply` 3) Delete all rows found by `grep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrie's comment is probably the way most users would approach this, but if you want to do this at the reading in stage, you can try this:

1. Read in your csv using `readLines` and make any lines that have the text *target* blank:

   ```
   temp = gsub(".*target.*", "", readLines("test.csv"))
   ```
2. Use `read.table` to convert `temp` to a `data.frame`. Since all lines that have the text *target* are now blank, the default `blank.lines.skip=TRUE` in `read.table` should correctly read in the rest of your data as a `data.frame`.

   ```
   read.table(text=temp, sep=",", header=TRUE)
   ```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered they are all very informative. I had no idea about the grep function or gsub.

Answer (score 3):

Use readLines:

```
lines <- readLines(file)
n.lines <- length(lines)
vec.1 <- rep(0, n.lines)
vec.2 <- rep(0, n.lines)
# more vectors as necessary

counter <- 0
for (i in 1:n.lines){           
  this.line <- strplit(lines[i], ",")
  if ("target" %in% this.line) next
  counter <- counter + 1
  vec.1[counter] <- this.line[1]
  vec.2[counter] <- this.line[2]
  # etc.
}

df <- data.frame(vec.1[1:counter], vec.2[1:counter])
```

You may have to change n.lines slightly and change the indexing of the for loop if your file has headers; two lines would change as follows:

```
n.lines <- length(lines) - 1
```

and

```
for(i in 2:(n.lines+1)){
```

Answer (score 1):

I would call `from.readLines <- readLines(filename)` and then just sub-select the rows that don't contain the target string: `data <- read.csv(text = from.readLines[-grep('target', from.readLines)], header = F)`.

The faster way to do it (if your file is huge) would be to `grep -v 'target' original.csv > new.csv` first on the command line and then run `read.csv(new.csv, ...)` in `R`.

But anyway,

```
> #Without header
> from.readLines <- c('afaf,afasf,target', 'afaf,target,afasf', 'dagdg,asgst,sagga', 'dagdg,dg,sfafgsgg')
> data <- read.csv(text = from.readLines[-grep('target', from.readLines)], header = F)
> print(data)
     V1    V2       V3
1 dagdg asgst    sagga
2 dagdg    dg sfafgsgg
> 
> #With header
> from.readLines <- c('var1,var2,var3', 'afaf,afasf,target', 'afaf,target,afasf', 'dagdg,asgst,sagga', 'dagdg,dg,sfafgsgg')
> data <- read.csv(text = from.readLines[-(grep('target', from.readLines[-1]) + 1)])
> print(data)
   var1  var2     var3
1 dagdg asgst    sagga
2 dagdg    dg sfafgsgg
```